# Segmentation fault when initialization array

Tags: c

I have a structure called string

```
typedef struct {
    char *s;
    int len;
} string_t;


typedef struct {
    uint32_t                numb;
} msg_t;
```

where in the function

```
void myfunct()
{
msg_t msg;
memset(&msg, 0, sizeof(msg));
msg.numb = 1;
char *ClientSendBuf[sizeof(msg)];
string_t buffer = {ClientSendBuf[sizeof(msg)],strlen(ClientSendBuf[sizeof(msg)])};
}
```

Tried to initialize an array (basically a buffer that I need to send later on) using UDP,
but it gives me an error of segmentation fault (on the third line in void myfunct. 
So the thing with buffer is that it should be a type of string_t, how can I fix this segmentation fault?

P.S. I forgot to mention, I want to copy the whole structure to the buffer variable (that should be type string_t) using memcopy. So am I doing the wrong thing above? How can I do this?

Comment: Do you simply want to initialize `buffer.s` to point to the raw representation of `msg` ? (as opposed to e.g. converting msg.numb to text first ?) . Bear in mind that strlen works on C strings. You don't have a string anywhere in this code.

Comment: @nos : YES!!! but I need to send the whole structure (basically contains a lot of different member type, including other structure). So i thought i start with the simple one, a structure that contains an integer as a struct member ,and copy everything to the buffer. I do not need to care about little endian/big endian as the client-server is on the same machine.

Comment: @Yodha : yes, sorry, i tried to simplify stuffs but I get all confused my self. I need an array of strings in the end, as the member of struct msg should contains difference types of member (uint32_t, str, int, etc etc). So I need to copy the whole structure to a buffer and send it using other API that accepts only string type..

Comment: @MetallicPriest : yes, sorry, i tried to simplify stuffs but I get all confused my self. I need an array of strings in the end, as the member of struct msg should contains difference types of member (uint32_t, str, int, etc etc). So I need to copy the whole structure to a buffer and send it using other API that accepts only string type..

Comment: In addition to what's already been said in the answers, using sizeof together with structs is most often a very bad idea, because a struct (or a union) can have padding bytes anywhere inside it, except at the very first element. 
Unless you have protective mechanisms against padding in place, never write code like this. Examples of such protective mechanisms are pre-processor checks or asserts. Or at the very least, a section with comments describing how the particular compiler handles padding and how your code relies on it.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things you have to consider in initializing your structure, as it has a pointer member `char *s` simple assignment will not work. Simple assignment will just copy the pointer address and not the content it is pointing to.
There are a few problems in your assignment code:
1. You declared an array of `char *` with `sizeof(msg)` elements, none of which are allocated memory; but your structure need `char *` and not `char *[]`
2. You are accessing an array element which is out of bounds (`ClientSendBuf[sizeof(msg)]`) and also not pointing to any valid address.
You can create a simple `char` array & copy it to the structure. As you are using a pointer member it is your responsibility to allocate memory and free memory.
Hope the code below can provide you with some references:

```
void myfunct()
{
   msg_t msg;
   memset(&msg, 0, sizeof(msg));
   msg.numb = 1;
   char ClientSendBuf[] = "This is my message";

   string_t buffer = {
                     strdup(ClientSendBuf), /*Can return NULL so add error check*/
                     strlen(ClientSendBuf)
   };
    /** Or **/
    string_t buffer;
    buffer.s = malloc(strlen(ClientSendBuf)+1);
    if(NULL == buffer.s)
    {
      /* Memory allocation failed. Handle error.*/
    }
    /* Zero fill */ 
    memset(buffer.s, 0, strlen(ClientSendBuf)+1);
    strcpy(buffer.s, ClientSendBuf);
    buffer.len = strlen(ClientSendBuf);
     /*Opeartions with buffer*/
     /*Call free in both cases !*/
     free(buffer.s);
}
```

Hope this help!

Answer (score 0):

ClientSendBuf - put some thing in it and also put it on the heap.

Answer (score 0):

I see two things that are wrong. First, accessing `ClientSendBuf[sizeof(msg)]` is undefined behavior, because that character is after the end of `CliendSendBuf`. Then you're assigning a `char` (namely `ClientSendBuf[sizeof(msg)]`)  when a `char *` is expected.
And if you want to use buffer outside that function you have to put `ClientSendBuf` on the heap, because it will be overwritten by other stack frames after you exit (i.e. sort of deleted), so the pointed data will be throwed off.
Now, since you want a copy of the whole `ClientSendBuff`, you need an array of `string_t`. Then, you assign every pointer in `ClienSendBuff` to `buffer`:

```
char *ClientSendBuff[sizeof(msg)];
string_t buffer[sizeof(msg)];
int i;

for(i = 0; i < sizeof(msg); i++) {
    ClientSendBuff[i] = malloc(100); // you have to initialize (and free when
    buffer[i].s = ClientSendBuff[i]; // you don't need them anymore) every pointer
    buffer[i].len = 100;
}
```

But I'm not sure if I got your point. How can a `char * []` fit in a `char*`?

Comment: strlen(ClientSendBuf) makes no sense (it is an uninitialized char** , and seemingly he want to stuff binary data in it).

Comment: @nos: ClientSendBuf is a char *. Agree on the strlen thing, though

Comment: ClientSendBuf is declared as `char *ClientSendBuf[sizeof(msg)]` - an array of char *, which makes `ClientSendBuf` a char ** when used in this context (as an argument to strlen)

Comment: @nos: oh yeah, you're right. Don't have seen C code for a while ;)

Comment: Likely all that's needed here is to drop the ClientSendBuff, and just do `string_t buffer = {(char*)&msg, sizeof msg};` Though, better not treat `buffer.s` as a string anywhere, or return `buffer` from that function.

Comment: @nos: why don't you make an own answer? :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you don't allocate memory to any element of *ClientSendBuf*. You should use *malloc* here to first allocate the memory.